# How to write this query for three tables

Tags: sql

I have 3 tables

Table: **agents**

```
Id | Name
---+------
 1 | a
 2 | b
 3 | c
```

Table: **passengers**

```
Id | AgentReference | Name
---+----------------+-----
 1 |       1        | E
 2 |       1        | F
 3 |       3        | ddd
```

Table: **visa_by_agent**

```
Id | agentId | visa_id | Total | Used
---+---------+---------+-------+------
 1 |   1     | aa      |   10  |   1
 2 |   1     | bb      |   20  |   2
 3 |   3     | dd      |   10  |   5
```

I want to show the result like

```
agentId | agentName | TotalPassenger | TotalVisa | TotalUsed
--------+-----------+----------------+-----------+-----------
   1    | a         |      2         |     30    |     3
   2    | b         |      0         |      0    |     0
   3    | c         |      1         |     10    |     5
```

I tried with this and getting syntax error

```
select  
    a.Id, a.Name, 
    vba.total, vba.used p.num_passengers 
from 
    agents a 
left join 
    (select 
         vba.AgentId, sum(Total) as Total, sum(Used) as Used 
     from 
         visa_by_agent vba 
     group by 
         vba.AgentId) vba on a.Id = vba.AgentId 
left join 
    (select p.AgentReference, count(*) as num_passengers 
     from passengers p 
     group by p.AgentReference) p on a.Id = p.AgentReference 
group by 
    agents.Id
```

Comment: I put what i tried so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are joining along different dimensions, resulting in a Cartesian product.  Aggregate *before* joining:

```
select a.Id, a.Name, vba.total, vba.used, p.num_passengers
from agents a left join
     (select vpa.AgentId, sum(Total) as Total, sum(Used) as Used
      from visa_by_agent vba
      group by vba.AgentId
     ) vba
     on a.Id = vba.AgentId left join
     (select p.agentId, count(*) as num_passengers
      from passengers p
      group by p.agentId
     ) p
     on a.Id = p.AgentId
```

Comment: I am testing this on my sqlite database browser with this.
select a.Id, a.Name, vba.total, vba.used p.num_passengers from agents a left join (select vpa.AgentId, sum(Total) as Total, sum(Used) as Used from visa_by_agent vba group by vba.AgentId) vba on a.Id = vba.AgentId left join (select p.AgentReference, count(*) as num_passengers from passengers p group by p.AgentReference) p on a.Id = p.AgentReference Group by agents.Id

Getting error

Comment: Hello I updated my question with your query. Its giving error.

Comment: @AndroidWorld . . . There should be no `group by` in the outer query.  I thought I deleted it but it appears to have stayed at the end of the last line.

Answer (score 1):

Try subqueries instead of joins.

```
SELECT 
  id AS agentId,
  name AS agentName,
  (SELECT count(*) FROM passengers WHERE agentId = a.id) AS TotalPassenger,
  (SELECT COALESCE(sum(Total), 0) FROM visa_by_agent WHERE agentId=a.id) AS TotalVisa
FROM
  agents AS a;
```

Comment: Don't know if that's important for OP, but you miss the conversion of TotalVisa from NULL to 0 for agent 2.

Comment: Total Visa shows null for the agents where no entry in visa by agent table

Comment: @AndroidWorld you can use `(SELECT COALESCE(sum(Total), 0)....` to get 0 instead of NULL.

Comment: (SELECT sum(Total) FROM visa_by_agent WHERE agentId=a.id) AS TotalVisa. I actually need to get sum(Total) and sum (Used) from visa_by_agent table. But this way I can use only total

Comment: @Rene Vogt, How to use sum(Total) and sum(Used) from visa_by_agent table?

Comment: @filiprem, I use you coalesce and gordon linof answer. Thank you.